# Mental activity that isn't thought

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a categorical noun to describe subjective activities that are prominent in conscious attention, but aren't thought?

*e.g. enjoying music, meditating.*

**Example Sentence:**

> In its whole capacity, the mind is not limited to thinking, but also to **XX** activities, which include experiencing music and meditation.

Comment: "other mental activities"?

Comment: *other phenomenological activities* or *non-cognitive activities* (where *cognitive* means of or relating to very thought)?

Comment: *other neurological activities*?

Comment: @Silenus "Non-cognitive" would exclude activities such as language learning, whereas I want to include them.

Comment: Language acquisition certainly requires directed thinking, doesn't it? What about ***passive activities*** such as dreaming, listening to music, meditating, watching a movie or television show, day-dreaming, obsessing, experiencing intrusive (uninvited) thoughts, hallucinating, spacing out, etc.? Where do you draw the line? What about paging through a collection of photographs or art? What about repetitive tasks that require no thought, such as assembly-line work or brushing one's teeth? What constitutes cognition? Does the dreamer "think"?

Comment: Enjoying music involves thinking. Meditation, too. Meditation is about clearing clutter out of the brain; that does not mean that thinking stops, it means that one focuses one thoughts. Per Sadhguru: "When you are doing your kriya or your meditation, you don’t mind if your kidneys or your lungs are functioning or if your heart is beating. You don’t mind all the other processes in the body – only your brain should not function! The notion that if you do something spiritual, your brain should stop working is simply wrong." Activities that are prominent in conscious attention are thought.

Comment: As my lama says (with a smile), "Meditation is not what you think."

Comment: Thinking is involved, though not necessary for certain mental activities. Language learning in a classroom situation would be complemented by directed thought. Language learning by a one year old, not so much.

There are different perspectives that could bear on this question, a neurological or philosophical perspective for example. surlawda asserts that music and meditation involve thinking, although I'm not convinced; dense thought would not be characteristic of these practices.

Perhaps this question makes some philosophical assumptions, and needs a definition of 'thought'.

Comment: "appreciation of music and meditation" are other than thinking? How do we define *thinking*?

Comment: Shall we call these *Cognitive Processes* or such? Meet me at: [cogsci.se]      "**cognitive process** - (psychology) the performance of some composite cognitive activity; an operation that affects mental contents; "the process of thinking"; "the cognitive operation of remembering"" http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cognitive+process

Comment: @Kris Yes, 'appreciation' is a poor choice of words because it suggests reflection. I mean the "qualitative state" of enjoying.

Comment: I think that the concept of "non-thought-based mental processes" is deeply flawed and is causing a lot of debate.  If you want to talk about mental activity which isn't conscious, why not just call it **unconscious mental activities**?

Comment: *thought:* 6. meditation, contemplation, or recollection: deep in thought. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/thought

Comment: You may be having in mind something like the difference between *perceptive* vs. *cognitive* processes.

Comment: @MaxWilliams  I don't think I claimed that thought and consciousness were synonymous.  Meditation is not an unconscious activity.

Answer (score 1):

**Sensuous**.

It means to be perceived or affected by the senses. It implies no thought or consideration, merely perception. Do not confuse with *sensual*, which has a more lascivious or hedonistic connotation. Note though, that this is an often conflated pair of words and your meaning may not get through to the entire readership.

> In its whole capacity, the mind is not limited to thinking, but also
>   to sensuous activities, which include experiencing music and
>   meditation.

Answer (score 0):

How about **experiential** [[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/experiential)] activities?

> Related to, derived from, or providing experience

As you've said, listening to music and meditating are both experiences, as opposed to thinking, which is more of a mental action. Thus, you can reword the sentence a bit to make it flow a little better:

> "In its whole capacity, the mind is not limited to thinking, but also to *experiential* activities, which include music and meditation."

Answer (score 0):

*Thought* is a very vexed term. Philosophers and cognitive scientists will disagree about what counts as thought. Some will even include your examples of enjoying music and meditating. Because it is not clear what *you* mean by *thought*, your question is hard to answer.

If by *thought* you mean something like "talking to yourself", then ***non-linguistic*** might fit the bill:

> In its whole capacity, the mind is not limited to thinking, but also to ***non-linguistic*** activities, which include experiencing music and meditation.

If by *thought* you mean something like "employing mental representations", then ***non-representational*** fits the bill:

> In its whole capacity, the mind is not limited to thinking, but also to ***non-representational*** activities, which include experiencing music and meditation.

You can also try ***non-cognitive***, where ***cognitive*** means (roughly) "of or relating to overt (representational) thought":

> In its whole capacity, the mind is not limited to thinking, but also to ***non-cognitive*** activities, which include experiencing music and meditation.

Lastly, you could try ***other phenomenological***, where ***phenomenological*** means "of or relating to what it's like to be conscious." This word strongly connotes those aspects of conscious experience that are hard to describe using language.

> In its whole capacity, the mind is not limited to thinking, but also to ***other phenomenological*** activities, which include experiencing music and meditation.

Honorary mentions include: ***purely qualitative*** and ***non-intentional***.